# Como criar uma medida para contar numeros distintos?

Tags: powerbi

Sou novo nesse mundo de power bi e estou precisando de um help, pode ser básico o que vou perguntar.

Tenho uma planilha em excel que me da mais ou menos a estrutur a baixo.

```
Protocolo                     Pedido       Item

ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17773959 | 5100712439 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17773959 | 5100712439 | 20
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17773959 | 5100712439 | 30
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17773959 | 5100712439 | 40
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714674 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714674 | 20
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714674 | 30
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714675 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714676 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714677 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714678 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714678 | 20
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714679 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714679 | 20
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714680 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714681 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714682 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714683 | 10
ACC003.2018.PRISMA.17938855 | 5100714683 | 20
```

Se vocês repararem bem, dá para perceber que o protocolo repete para o pedido, pois ele tem um item para o pedido.

O que quero contar é a quantidade de pedidos, por exemplo, nesse bloquinho do excel que compartilhei, teriam 11 pedidos distintos

Comment: Boa tarde Gabriel, Você pode utilizar a opção Group By do Power BI. Caso queira uma referencia, essa pagina tem bastante info sobre isso:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/power-bi/desktop-common-query-tasks Abs,
Rodrigo Melo

Comment: Amigão, não funcionou

Answer (score -2, accepted):

voce pode criar uma medida como abaixo:

medida = DISTINCTCOUNT(PEDIDOS)

acho que é a maneira mais facil.

Answer (score 3):

@RodrigoMelo estava certo, você tem que se agrupar duas vezes:

O primeiro pode ser agrupado por soma (`Items`) para eliminar duplicatas em `Pedidos`.

O segundo tem que agrupar com duas condições uma que conta as `Pedidos` e a segunda que adiciona os `Items`.

[image]

Advanced Editor (Power M code):

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\david\Desktop\stack.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table2_Table = Source{[Item="Table2",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Table2_Table, {"Protocolo", "Pedido"}, {{"Item", each List.Sum([Item]), type number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Protocolo"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"Item", each List.Sum([Item]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows1"
```

Comment: Amigão, com o DISTINCTCOUNT(Protocolo) funcionou!!